# Is code signing not handled in Xcode 5? "code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, codesign, code-signing-certificate

How do I deal with this error? I recently switched a new laptop and I'm having trouble submitting my app to the App Store.

It's complaining about my code signing identity, how do I go about fixing this? I thought Xcode 5 handled a bunch of these profiles and provisioning automatically now?

Comment: As always, you can't use beta tools to submit apps to the store. Use Xcode 5.0.2, not the 5.1 beta.

Comment: Using Xcode 5.0.2 and nothing changed.

Comment: Using Xcode 5.0.2 you are still getting an error about iOS 7.1? That makes no sense.

Comment: I'm getting an identical error, but the SDK version is switched to the corresponding one...

Comment: I think I may have run into this once... go through your Target and your Project build settings, and hit delete/backspace on any bold setting involving architecture, provisioning, and code signing.  Also go to the General tab on the Target and make sure your Team is selected. save that then set them how you need.  It's like the project file got upgraded poorly in my instance.  Also you can go into the Xcode preferences and in Accounts refresh the dev account under "view details"